# How to get the id's of selected checkboxes which are displaying dynamically in android?

Tags: android

In my project I am **displaying the checkboxes dynamically**. But I want to get the id values of all the **checkboxes that are selected**. In my application the user will select multiple checkboxes and I need to store those selected checkboxes id's in an arraylist. **How can I get the selected checkboxes id's?**

My Code:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
  View view = convertView;
  try
  {
  if (view == null) 
   {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, null); 
    }
    final UserBO listItem = mList.get(position);            
    if (listItem != null) 
      {

    Rl = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chklnlayout);

    ArrayList<UserBO> mList1;

    CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[20]; 

    for(int k=0; k<list.size(); k++)
    { 
     System.out.println("list in for loop"+list.get(0));
     arr = list.get(k);
     cbs[k] = new CheckBox(getContext());
     Rl.addView(cbs[k]);
     cbs[k].setText((CharSequence) arr.get(2));
     cbs[k].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));  
    } 

   }
}
catch(Exception e){
  String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"hii":e.getMessage();
  Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);  
}
return view;
}
```

Please help me regarding this....Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code for loop,

Write this line,

```
cbs[k].setId(k);
```

Now `implements OnClickListener` in your activity

in

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
int checkBoxId  = v.getId();    
}
```

or something like,

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Selected CheckBox ID" + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

And let me know what happen..

Comment: just implements OnClickListener in your activity.

Comment: hi I have edited my code..please check once..I am displaying the checkboxes in list and so I wrote the code in getview method. Now if I implement onclicklistener to my activity how can I write the onclick method in getview method? Please help me regarding this

Comment: What you want to achieve at last?

Comment: hi those checkboxes are options for each question. At last I need to compare the user checked options with that in database and should print the correct answers in green color and wrong answers in red color

Comment: put this in for loop... cbs[k].setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
           
          }
        });

Answer (score 0):

U Can Implement Like this.

```
  checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                System.out.println("checkBox.isChecked()"
                        + checkBox.isChecked());
                if (checkBox.isChecked() == true) {
                    PhoneListCheckbox.phonelist.get(position).setChecked(
                            true);
                } else {
                    PhoneListCheckbox.phonelist.get(position).setChecked(
                            false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out(I haven't tested it):

```
final HashMap<Integer,Integer> myList=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();      
for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
{
   final CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(context);
   cb.setId(i);
   myList.put(i, 0);
   final int pos=i;
   cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

         if(cb.isChecked())
        myList.put(pos, 1);// checkbox checked
         else
        myList.put(pos,0);//checkbox unchecked                  
    }
   });
}
```

And you can access the status of checkboxes by just `int status=myList.get(checkbox_id);` whenever you need.here 1 indicates checked and 0 indicates unchecked for checkboxes.

Comment: using your code I think 20 Anonymous classes are created of new OnCheckedChangeListener() also extra HashMap collection is required to store the id of checked checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved when we apply *"setOnClickListener"* on child check box of parent dynamic created Linear layout. I have added check box using *"getLayoutInflater()"* and set id for each check box.For it u can see below code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < JAS.length(); i++) {

   View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.return_child, null);
   chk = (CheckBox) child.findViewById(R.id.Product);
   chk.setText(c.optString("name"));
   chk.setId(i);

   ll.addView(child);

   chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           String chk = null;
           chk = Integer.toString(v.getId());
           if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
               selchkboxlist.add(chk);

           } else {
               selchkboxlist.remove(chk);
           }
       }
   });
}
```

Here selchkboxlist is *"List"*
 same as below :

**List selchkboxlist = new ArrayList();**

Now On button click you can apply below code for accessing id of selected check box.

```
ReturnProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        for (int p=0;p<selchkboxlist.size();p++){
            String Length = selchkboxlist.get(p);
            int ln = Integer.parseInt(Length);
            Toast.makeText(ReturnOrders.this, ""+ln, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```